# Is possible to add an image that rotates when i rotate the 3d chart?

Tags: highcharts

is possible to to add an image that it rotates when I I rotate the 3D chart?

My chart is "3d scatter draggable chart"

and i add an image in this way:

```
     events: {
                    load: function() {
                        this.renderer.image("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=64.775,-17&zoom=7&size=320x320&maptype=satellite", "0%", "50%", 60, 20).add();
                    }
                },
```

the image must be at the top of chart, and must follow the chart.. :

http://i59.tinypic.com/25focd2.png

http://i61.tinypic.com/23ma81w.png

the black rect will be my image..

i'm going crazy, for me it is too difficult and I do not know if it is realizable.

Please help me :(

Comment: It should be possible, but may be hard. I created simple example how to update the image, see: http://jsfiddle.net/hp08pnpe/ and http://jsfiddle.net/hp08pnpe/1/

Comment: very hard!  thank you for the suggestion!! I think that is better latter links...  and i believe that must be also the "translate" (like transformation). What do you think about?

Comment: Yes, you are most probably right :)